# How to create custom product image attribute in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, admin, image-upload

I want to create custom product image attribute in **magento2.2.5**?

Created a custom product image attribute but not able to save the image

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Amy/ImageUploader/Model/Attribute/Product/Image.php

```
<?php

namespace Amy\ImageUploader\Model\Attribute\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Image extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend {

    protected $_uploaderFactory;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        //echo $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        //Out Put: custom_product_image
        //echo '<br>';
        //var_dump($object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName()));
        //Out Put: NULL
        //var_dump($this->getAttribute()->getName() . '_additional_data');
        //Out Put: NULL
        //var_dump($object->getData('name'));
        //Out Put: string(16) "Joust Duffle Bag"
        //exit;
        $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName() . '_additional_data');
        echo"aaa";
        exit;

        if (empty($value) && empty($_FILES)) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete'])) {
            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), '');
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
            return $this;
        }

        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('catalog/product/');

        try {

            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $this->getAttribute()->getName()]);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($path);

            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), $result['file']);
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() != \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::TMP_NAME_EMPTY) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    } }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can create new product `Media` attribute from admin

Answer (score 3):

Hi this is the good code to create programatically a product image attribute, and add it to images group, tested on magento 2.3.3
File : upgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace YourExtension\Catalog\Setup;
class UpgradeSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
/**
 * Eav setup factory
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function upgrade(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6', '<')) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'color_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'color_image',
                'input' => 'media_image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 30,
                'frontend' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true
            ]
        );
        $id = $eavSetup->getAttributeId(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'color_image'
        );

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $attributeSetId, 'image-management', $id, 10);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> create Attribute

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;


    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0) {


            $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'product_banner');


            $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product :: ENTITY, 'category_banner', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Category Banner',
                    'input' => 'image',
                    'backend' => 'Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Bannerimage',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 110,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                    "default" => "",
                    "class" => "",
                    "note" => ""
                ]
            );

        }

    }
}
```

> Extends Uploder

```
namespace Vendorname\Module name\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Imageuploader\Productbanner;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Productbanner extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image\Upload
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Catalog::product');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('product_banner');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<field name="product_banner" sortOrder="40" formElement="fileUploader">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</elementTmpl>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Product Banner</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <required>false</required>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <fileUploader>
                <settings>
                    <required>false</required>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="path_to_your admin_controller"/>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                    <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                </settings>
            </fileUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

> etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendorname\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Productbanner\Imageuploader\Productbanner\Classname">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Vendorname\Modulename\Virtualtypename</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Vendorname\Modulename\\Virtualtypename" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/product</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/product/Banner</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\DataProvider" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Product\DataProvider" />
</config>
```

> In Model/Product/DataProvider.php get The Data from attribute
>   You can also use after before save method to customise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here. Depending on the purpose of this attribute, you're going to use a different approach.

**Option 1: Image uploader button**

There is no "Image Upload" input type, so if you really want a button to upload images on the product page, you're going to need to do some customization.

You're going to have to make a module with an **InstallData.php** and add an attribute via the `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory`. This attribute is going to need a **frontend model** and a **backend model**.

Here is a draft of how the file might look like:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, 'custom_image_uploader', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom Image Uploader',
            'input' => 'text',
            'frontend' => \Vendor\CustomModule\Frontend\ImageUploader::class,
            'backend' => \Vendor\CustomModule\Backend\ImageUploader::class,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 103,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
            'group' => 'General'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Image Role**

Another approach might be to add an extra image role to your Images & Videos. You can easily add this by adding a new attribute in **Stores -> Product**. Fill in the fields to your liking, but make sure that the **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner** is set on **Media Image**. Save it and you will be able to assign images to your custom image role on your product page.

> **[EDIT]**

In case your opting for option 1, your backend model should look similar to this

```
namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Model\Config\Backend;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File\RequestData\RequestDataInterface;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;

class ImageUpload extends Image
{
    /**
     * The tail part of directory path for uploading
     */

    const UPLOAD_DIR = 'vendor/images';
    protected $uploadDirExtend = '';

    /**
     * Upload max file size in kilobytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_maxFileSize = 2048;

    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private $http;

    /**
     * Return path to directory for upload file
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param RequestDataInterface $requestData
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param AbstractDb|null $resourceCollection
     * @param Http $http
     * @param array $data
     */

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        RequestDataInterface $requestData,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        Http $http,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $uploaderFactory, $requestData, $filesystem, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
        $this->http = $http;
    }

    /**
     * Return path to directory for upload file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getUploadDir()
    {
        return $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR . $this->uploadDirExtend));
    }

    /**
     * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save uploaded file before saving config value
     *
     * Save changes and delete file if "delete" option passed
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $files = $this->http->getFiles();

        if (isset($value)) {
            $deleteFlag = is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete']);
            if (isset($files['groups'])) {
                $fileTmpName = $files['groups'][$this->getGroupId()]['fields'][$this->getField()]['value'];
                if ($this->getOldValue() && ($fileTmpName || $deleteFlag)) {
                    $this->_mediaDirectory->delete(self::UPLOAD_DIR . '/' . $this->getOldValue());
                }
            }
        }
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }

    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'svg'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your option 1, the image attribute is displaying perfectly in admin. But I am not able to save the image.

Comment: That's probably because your backend model isn't working properly. I'll edit my post once I got it working.

Comment: Okay thank you, will be waiting for your answer.

Comment: I have updated my post. If you want more support, we can always help you through our website.

Comment: Again not able to save the image.

Comment: I have update my question, can you please have a look on it..